# How to use a netbeans "friend" module in own modules?

Tags: java, netbeans, module

I'm trying to write a small module for netbeans.
Now, everything compiles, but when I try to run the module the follwing error occurs:

The module mtzoutgoings is not a friend of C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 8.0.2\java\modules\org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject.jar

I've read that in the jar's MANIFEST.MF there is a section "OpenIDE-Module-Friends" in which all classes are referenced that are allowed to use the jar.
Hm. So, is there any way that I can use it for my module as well, without beeing a "friend" of the jar ?

thanks for any hint!
Thorsten

Answer (score 2):

I'm developing a module for NetBeans. When I tried to run my module, I received the following error message:

> The module my_module_name is not a friend of
>   /home/antonio/netbeans-8.2/php/modules/org-netbeans-modules-php-api-phpmodule.jar

What I did to get rid of that error message: I expanded **Libraries**, right-clicked **PHP Module API** and clicked **Edit**. In the dialog box, I checked **Implementation Version** and clicked **OK**.

Reference: https://markmail.org/message/qulevpr647bpvshg